# ModuleNotFoundError but path is in sys.path

Tags: python, python-module, pythonpath

I have the following project structure:

```
my-project
  src
    __init__.py
    main.py
    utils
      __init__.py
      configs
    modules
      __init__.py
      other_module.py
```

My main.py script is as follows:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import sys, os
print("cwd: {}".format(os.getcwd()))
# appending directory to sys.path
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
# printing to check if it worked
for p in sys.path:
    print(p)
from src.utils.configs import read_config

if __name__=='__main__':
   # do stuff
   pass
```

The run keeps failing with **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.utils'**

I think this could be due to another module being called *src*. Below my verbose output:

```bash
import 'pathlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001CC4C31B370>
cwd: C:\Users\UserName\LOCAL\my-project
C:\Users\UserName\LOCAL\my-project\src
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python310.zip
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\UserName\LOCAL\my-project
# C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\src\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-310.pyc matches C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\src\__init__.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\src\\__pycache__\\__init__.cpython-310.pyc'
import 'src' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001CC4C147D60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UserName\LOCAL\my-project\src\nats_minimal_listener.py", line 7, in <module>
    from src.utils.configs import read_config
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.utils'
```

A few points:

1. Please **don't mark it as duplicate before reading it**: I looked at *many* other answers and none works.
2. Please don't suggest writing

   ```py
    from utils.configs import read_configs
   ```

   This only solves the problem for main.py, but I have to import src.utils.configs from other files (like other_module.py)
3. **Why rearranging the file structure is not practical:** If I want to import a "configs" module from all submodules, this would need to be a subfolder of all submodules and would need to be duplicate in all submodules, like this:

```
my-project
  src
    __init__.py
    main.py
    utils
      __init__.py
      configs
    module1
      __init__.py
      other_module.py
      utils
        __init__.py
        configs
     module2
      __init__.py
      other_module.py
      utils
        __init__.py
        configs
```

Comment: there is no _ _ init _ _.py in src, so it is not  a module, that is why it does not work. Please review how python module structure works.

Comment: sorry there is, I added it. My question stands

Comment: Move other folders into `src` folder then add `__init__.py` at the root of src

Comment: doesn't work, I need to import src.utils from other folders within src (e.g. src/modules)

Comment: You are trying to import `read_config` from the file `src/utils/configs.py`, shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: The content of the _ _ init _ _.py file matters, you need to include that information, if its empty, that is the reason it does not work.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy first Google result below: ***Leaving this file empty is normal and even good practise.***
https://readthedocs.web.cern.ch/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=238092978#:~:text=__init__.py%20file%20in%20Python%20Packages&text=Used%20to%20gather%20all%20package,sub%2Dpackages%20need%20to%20share.

Comment: You can also import all the submodules in the into your modules to the `__init__.py` to act as master modules then import the other modules from src module. This will help  do a relative import of the nested modules to avoid circular import

Comment: I don't know if is it a typo in your post, but the `configs` file should be `configs.py`

Answer (score 0):

Please check on this format
[image]

I hope the folder structure and nature of imports help you relate the imports
It's best you re-organise your codebase to make the imports a bit easier
[image]

To make this clear `src` is the root folder as you have described
Meaning once you add other modules in the `src` folder. they will be relative to the `src` folder
Adding `__init__.py` in the `src` makes it a module and the other submodules under it should have `__init__.py` in them will be relative already so a file like `main.py` in the `src` you can import using
`from module.submodule import module` instead of `from src.module.submodule import module`
So in your imports don't use the `src....`

Comment: I don't understand, what should I do?

Comment: Don't  use `from src.utils.configs import read_config` instead use `from utils.configs import read_config` Try that out please